# How to return PromiEvent from async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, web3js

I need to return `PromiEvent` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-core-promievent) from `async` function. But I always got a common `Promise` without `on` handlers. Here is the test code:
const Web3PromiEvent = require('web3-core-promievent')

```
async function sleep() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
}

async function inner() {
    const pe = new Web3PromiEvent()

    await sleep()

    pe.eventEmitter.emit('done', 'ok')
    pe.resolve('ok')

    return pe
}

async function main() {
    const pe = inner()

    pe.on('done', console.log)

    const res = await pe
    console.log(res)
}

main()
```

Here the example in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/node-js-forked-lw19bp?file=/src/index.js

How properly return `PromiEvent` from `async` function?

Comment: `PromiEvent` is an NPM package and so is subject to quirky behaviour depending on what version is used of the library in question and any it is interacting with. Therefore, please recreate your bug in a sandbox environment so answerers can correct it.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer I've added a sandbox example link on the post

Comment: Sadly the sandbox freezes when I try to open it but good luck!